# Estimating sample size from (intra/inter) subsample variance

Tags: sampling, sample-size, resampling

If samples taken from the population vary from one another by a certain amount, while the differences between the types of sample in any sampling event vary only by a certain amount, what formula can be used to calculate the sizes of the samples? For example, if you take a random sample for A and B from the population and another random sample for A and B from the population simultaneously, and the averages for A1 and B1 differ from A2 and B2, how can you estimate the sizes of these random samples (given that they are the same) from the degree of difference?

Comment: Are you looking at the difference between $A_1 - B_1$ v. $A_2 - B_2$? And do you assume that the sample for A and B are (in both draws) the same size?

Comment: No, A1-A2 and B1-B2. (If you assumed spread you could just use A1-A2 to estimate sample size.) And no to the second question.